# How to run multiple bash commands (with piping), within Docker Compose

Tags: bash, docker-compose

I have a lengthy bash command in a Docker Compose:

```
  command: bash -c 'wait-for-it emul:4000 && (firebase-prime ... | grep -v -E "Do not use with production credentials") && npx vite --port 3000'
```

If `firebase-prime` was not found, or it would fail, the whole command would still pass and Docker Compose keep running. How to make it fail, and Docker Compose to bring all the dependency services down, as well?

Comment: I will answer this on my own. Feel this would be important to be available in SO and didn't find it asked, earlier.

Comment: Added a PR to Docker docs: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/13265

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting:

```
$ bash -c 'false | cat' && echo a
a
$ bash -c 'set -o pipefail; false | cat' && echo a
$ bash -o pipefail -c 'false | cat' && echo a
```

Adding `-o pipefail` seems like the lightest syntax.

```
  command: bash -o pipefail -c 'wait-for-it emul:4000 && (firebase-prime ... | grep ...)`
```

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/mohanpedala/1e2ff5661761d3abd0385e8223e16425) a good description of `pipefail` scenario. `firebase-prime` could be writing the pattern expected by grep to stdout but exiting with error code (non-zero). Is `grep` the first command after `firebase-prime`?

Comment: Check this example `(echo 'Production' && false ) | grep 'Production' && echo $?
# Result: Production
# exit code: 0`. The exit code of the command before grep is 1 but the exit code of grep is 0

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using `set -o pipefail` is not possible.
`firebase-prime` could be writing the pattern expected by `grep` to stdout but exiting with error code (non-zero). In the example below the left side of the pipe "fails" but grep still succeeds.

```
((echo 'Production' && false ) | grep 'Production') && echo $?
```

Result:

```
Production
0
```

An alternative to `set -o pipefail` is to use `PIPESTATUS` builtin variable.
Printing all exit statuses of the pipe

```
(echo 'Production' && false ) | grep 'Production' ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
Production
1 0
```

Test exit status of first command that fails but still `grep` its stdout. The last command is not executed.

```
((echo 'Production' ; false ) | grep 'Production' ; [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]] ) && echo "Another command"
# output: Production
```

The exit status of the subshell is given by the `[[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]]` test.
If the first command in the pipe succeeds then the last command will be executed

```
((echo 'Production' ; true ) | grep 'Production' ; [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]] ) && echo "Another command"
# output: Production
#         Another command
```

Executing `(echo 'Production' ; false )` in a subshell simulates a command that prints to stdout but returns a non-zero exit status.

A weird case with output on stdout but command not found

```
(echo 'Production' && fake ) | grep 'Production' ; echo -e "Left side exit status: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}\nRight side exit status: ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
fake: command not found
Production
Left side exit status: 127
Right side exit status: 0
```

Comment: My aim was to provide a simple syntax for authors of Docker Compose YAML files, if they wish to have multiple commands within the YAML instead of external `.sh` files - like I often do.

While I appreciate your reply, I wouldn't personally start placing any extra things within the *command itself* since that only complicates matters.

Comment: Sure, np. Learned a couple of things myself.